# Should I create a separate AppicationInsights instance per WebJob?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

I'm wondering are there any best practices or recommendations out there on using Application Insights to monitor web jobs. At the moment I have all my app service and web jobs logs going to the one AI instance and there is alot of noise in there.

Specifically should I:

- create a separate AI instance for all the web jobs
- or create a separate AI instance per web job.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally use [one instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-faq#should-i-use-single-or-multiple-application-insights-resources) for each system in your environment, but separate out dev, test, and prod. This is to make it simpler to track dependencies as jobs move throughout the system. So with multiple web apps, you might group an API, a separate web app that serves the front end content, and any web jobs that support those two apps. On another you may have just a single web app or web job that acts independently from the rest of your apps.

However, you should choose the number of Application Insights instances that best fit your situation. If it would work better for you to split each web job then you can certainly do that. You can [query across App Insights instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query), so you don't completely lose the ability to join the data from different services together if you choose to split them into separate App Insights instances.